# hook_menu issues

Tags: php, function, drupal

I have a hook menu

```
$items['node/%/delete'] = array(
        'title' => 'Delete',
        'load arguments' => array(3),
        'description' => 'Confirm the action.',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('_mymodule_delete', 1),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'weight' => -4,
    );
return $items;
```

What do I need to do to make sure the following function gets to work (and the variables get their values):

`function _mymodule_delete ($form, $form_state, $node) {

          ...

}`

In orther words, how do I get values in the three arguments given (`$form`, `$form_state` and `$node`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I'll have another go...

The only argument(s) you need to pass to `drupal_get_form`, other than the name of the form itself, are arguments specific to that form function; `$form` and `$form_state` are automatically added for you. So if you want to call a form with a signature of `_mymodule_delete($form, $form_state, $node)` you would use this code:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('_mymodule_delete', $the_node);
```

When you apply this to the menu router, all you're looking to do is pass the loaded `$node` through as an argument to `drupal_get_form` in the same way. Your router item would look like this:

```
$items['node/%node/delete'] = array(
  'title' => 'Title',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('_mymodule_delete', 1),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'weight' => -4,
);
```

Your original example is missing the `access arguments`/`access callback` attribute which would make your page inaccessible (403 status) so I've added in the 'standard' access arguments of `access content`. You'll probably want to change this for your own needs.

The string `node/%node/delete` (the router path) and the page arguments array are the bits you're probably interested in here. When you want to pass an argument from the URL to a callback function you simply include it's 'index' as one of the page arguments. This index comes from a zero-based array of the router path when split by the separator (`/`).

In this example the three parts of the path are:

```
0 => 'node',
1 => '%node',
2 => 'delete'
```

As the variable element of the path is in index position `1`, that's the number we pass to the `page arguments` array.

Just to make it a little more complicated, the variable passed in through the path can also be passed to a load function *before* it's passed to the `page callback` function. For some reason the naming convention in Drupal is that a function with the name of the variable with `_load` appended to it will be the name of the function called.

So in this case, `node_load` is called. If your router path was, for example, `books/%book` then a function called `book_load` would be called to prepare the variable to be passed to the `page callback` function.

The load function is optional, if your path was `node/%/delete` then the argument passed to your form callback would be the exact string (in this case a node ID) from the URL.

I'm sure you've seen it but the [`hook_menu()` documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) tries its best to explain all this, I can understand why it would be difficult to comprehend though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid I gave a bad example :) I'm not aiming for the delete-option. It was just an example. In fact, it's a custom function in my custom module. It has nothing to do with delete :)

Comment: Ah! I've edited the answer above with a whole new one, hope it does the trick :)

Comment: Holy crap, that's some massive answer! But it did help me out a lot more as the Drupal documentation did. Thanks a million! Again... :) Two more questions though. What do I have to do to make a change in the loaded node in `_mymodule_delete` function? And what is the real function of the `access callback` arguments? You gave `access` and `content`, but what are the possibilities and the function of those items?

Comment: Heh yeah it just kinda spilled out :) It depends what part of the node you want to change, is it a field value?

Comment: That `access arguments` thing got me for a long time until I realised it's just a string, as defined by some module implementing [`hook_permission`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7). The `access callback` is the function called to determine access for the page (it defaults to the system function [`user access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_access/7)). The `access arguments` is just an array of parameters to pass to that function

Comment: Yep, I want to change the status (published or not). Right now, I have something like `$node->status = '0'`, but I'm guessing Drupal needs some kind of submit in order to get the changes to work. I've tested `node_sumbit`, but that didn't work out...

Comment: So close, you just need `$node->status = 0; node_save($node);` :)

Comment: Oh damn, so close :) and you rock! awesome! Thanks a trillion!